# java to node.js code conversion

Tags: java, node.js

I am using following java code to unwrap the data. But i don't know how could i write same for Node.js ? Java code is shown below:

```
public void receiveEvent(String forTopic, MqttMessage event)
        throws MqttException {
    Object obj = null;
    java.io.ByteArrayInputStream bstream = new   java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(
            event.getPayload());
    try {
        java.io.ObjectInputStream st = new java.io.ObjectInputStream(
                bstream);
        obj = st.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DataWrapper dt = (DataWrapper) obj;
 s.notifyReceived(forTopic, dt.getObject(), dt.getDevice());
```

Code for data wrapper is shown below:

```
public class DataWrapper implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Device device;
Object object;
public void setDevice(Device deviceInfo) {
    this.device = deviceInfo;
}
public void setObject(Object object) {
    this.object = object;
}
public Device getDevice() {
    return device;
}
public Object getObject() {
    return object;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into MQTT.js. It's available on NPM here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt

For a full example, we'll need to know a bit more about your setup and what you're trying to do... but here's the example copied over from MQTT,js

```
var mqtt    = require('mqtt');
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org');

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('presence');
  client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt');
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer 
  console.log(message.toString());
  client.end();
});
```

It's probably pretty close to what you want to start with.

Comment: @Julian- I know but i am new to node.js that's why asking such question. Already i did with java code.

Comment: We're going to need a bit more than that example code to really help you.. The only thing that your code is doing is converting the payload of your received event through 3 different kinds of stream before calling "notifyReceived" on a mysterious object "s".

Comment: @Julian- Could you please refer my following post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429380/mqtt-communication-between-node-js-and-java