# MQTT Java publisher and Nodejs subscriber

Tags: java, node.js, mqtt

In my current project, we are trying to enable communication between two software component as follow. Here, the `Temperaturesensor` (written in `JavaSE`) component periodically publishing sensor measurement, written in MQTT JavaSE Publisher. And `CalculateTemp`(written in `Nodejs`) component has subscribed using MQTT Nodejs and received data. My problem is -- when data is received at `CalculateAvgTemp`component is **Junk** (Possibly, the problem is `TemperatureSensor` is sending data in `byte[]` and on the `calculateAvgTemp` component side, the data is not converted from `byte[]`.-- How can I convert the byte[] data to JSON format????)

[image]
The Publish method at `TemperatureSensor` as follows. **Please note that data are converted to byte, before publishing to MQTT broker.**

```
public void publish(String topicName, Object arg, Device deviceInfo) {

    DataWrapper dw = new DataWrapper();
    dw.setObject(arg);
    dw.setDevice(deviceInfo);

    java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream bstream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
    java.io.ObjectOutputStream st;

    try {
        st = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(bstream);
        st.writeObject(dw);
        st.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] bytes = bstream.toByteArray();

    try {

        pub.publish(topicName, 0, bytes);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

On data receiving side, the `CalculateAvgTemp`, the code is as follows:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt'); // no count for NodeRED
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org:1883'); 
var NUM_SAMPLE_FOR_AVG = 5;
var numSample = 0;
var tempCelcius = 0;
var currentAvg = 0;
client.subscribe('tempMeasurement'); 
client.on('message', function(topic, payload) { 
    if (topic.toString() == "tempMeasurement") {

        // Here, we may need to convert the byte[] array.
        // But I do not know-- how can I convert byte[] array to JSON.  

        var sensorMeasurement=JSON.parse(payload);

        if (numSample <= NUM_SAMPLE_FOR_AVG) {
            numSample = numSample + 1;
            if (sensorMeasurement.unitOfMeasurement == 'F') {
                tempCelcius = ((sensorMeasurement.tempValue - 32) * (5 / 9));
            } else {
                tempCelcius = sensorMeasurement.tempValue;
            }
            currentAvg = parseFloat(currentAvg) + parseFloat(tempCelcius);
            if (numSample == NUM_SAMPLE_FOR_AVG) {
                currentAvg = currentAvg / NUM_SAMPLE_FOR_AVG;
                var avgTemp = {
                    "tempValue" : parseFloat(currentAvg),
                    "unitOfMeasurement" : sensorMeasurement.unitOfMeasurement
                };
                client.publish('roomAvgTempMeasurement', JSON  
                        .stringify(avgTemp)); 
                console.log("Publishing Data roomAvgTempMeasurement "); 
                numSample = 0;
                currentAvg = 0;
            }
        }
    } 
});
```

there is possible duplication of question is [MQTT communication between nodejs and java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429380/mqtt-communication-between-node-js-and-java?rq=1)
But, the proposed solution is not working or I am not able to understand it clearly that can solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ObjectOutputStream will convert an object into a Serialized Java Object stream, this is Java's internal object notation and can not be understood by anything else (easily).

You need to use a library like the one from [json.org](http://json.org/) to build a JSON object (or build one by hand as a string as shown in the linked question) that holds the same state as your DataWrapper object, then have the JSON object output as a string which can be send as the byte payload of the MQTT message.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestions. I have partially resolved the problem now. Now, I am getting not junk characters, but getting the result in `ï¿½ï¿½*{"tempValue":25.0,"unitOfMeasurement":"C"}` (some junk characters before JSON values. What could be the solution of it???

Comment: We have resolved this issue now by extracting JSON data.    `bytes = new String(bytes, "UTF-8").substring(7).getBytes();`